# JavaFX Embedd a Region into a specific Pane

Tags: javafx, region, pane

I want to use the graph-editor from tesis-dynaware (https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/graph-editor/wiki/1.%20Getting%20Started) in a specific pane.

Unfortunately the model is a JavaFX Region. Is there any way to embedd a JavaFX Region into a Split Pane?
Scene Builder offers a Region under Miscellaneous, but I can't fill it with data. I know that a Region is not designated to work that way...

Edit:
This is the code and it does not show the graphEditor. If i put it directly into the scene it works.

```
public class Flowcharteditor extends Application {


@FXML Pane pane = new Pane();


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    GraphEditor graphEditor = new DefaultGraphEditor();
    GModel model = GraphFactory.eINSTANCE.createGModel();
    graphEditor.setModel(model);
    addNodes(model);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    pane.getChildren().addAll(graphEditor.getView());

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}


private GNode createNode() {

GNode node = GraphFactory.eINSTANCE.createGNode();

GConnector input = GraphFactory.eINSTANCE.createGConnector();
GConnector output = GraphFactory.eINSTANCE.createGConnector();

input.setType("left-input");
output.setType("right-output");

node.getConnectors().add(input);
node.getConnectors().add(output);

return node;
}

private void addNodes(GModel model) {

GNode firstNode = createNode();
GNode secondNode = createNode();

firstNode.setX(150);
firstNode.setY(150);

secondNode.setX(400);
secondNode.setY(200);
secondNode.setWidth(200);
secondNode.setHeight(150);

Commands.addNode(model, firstNode);
Commands.addNode(model, secondNode);
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

[Region](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) is a subclass of Node. You can embed it like any other Node.

According to the documentation of your link, i. e.

```
GraphEditor graphEditor = new DefaultGraphEditor();

Scene scene = new Scene(graphEditor.getView(), 800, 600);
```

all you'd have to do is

```
splitPane.getItems().add( graphEditor.getView());
```

Comment: Nobody can see what you're doing there. What is pane? What does addNodes do? etc. If you want help, you should provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've put in all the code, but the Pane is just a standard pane and the methods are taken from the example in the links. They add some nodes to the model.

Comment: No idea how / if they resize the view once the parent changes or how large the view is. Try a BorderPane and setCenter instead of a Pane.